# Is there a website where we can find all kind of statistics related to the European football?

Tags: football, statistics

I'm a huge fan of football and I simply want to know if a website dedicate to statistics about this sport exists. I always read articles about football in which journalists provide statistics and I always wonder where do they find them.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is a source request. See our [help center](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: A related question: [Where can I get data for individual player statistics in European football?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/q/20475)

Answer (score 2):

A website like [Soccerway](http://www.soccerway.com) offers stats on football from all around the world.