# Where can I get data for individual player statistics in European football?

Tags: football, statistics, la-liga, bundesliga, serie-a

I am doing a research paper on European football, and I am looking for individual player statistics. For example, numbers on detailed stats like shots, shots on target, passes, tackles, blocks, interceptions, clearances, aerial battles won/lost, fouls, offsides, etc. I am able to find data for the English Premier League on the Premier League Stats Centre. However, I am finding it quite difficult to find similar data for other leagues such as La Liga, Bundesliga, Ligue 1, and Serie A.

Answer (score 1):

I found two really nice links:

- The [WhoScore](https://www.whoscored.com/Statistics) gives you a lot of information. You just need to click
  the league you want to observe.
- [Roto Wire](https://www.rotowire.com/soccer/stats.php?league=LIGA) is like WhoScore but with more advanced stats (you need to subscribe on this one).

You can access to the official league website and there you have a lot of statistics, for example, [Bundesliga](https://www.bundesliga.com/en/stats/bundesliga).

Answer (score 0):

For the Bundesliga, [kicker](https://www.kicker.de) is among the best when it comes to individual level data.

Answer (score -1):

I think optasports is the best website for all the statistics related to football.
https://www.optasports.com/

also visit:
http://www.squawka.com/en/football-player-rankings

Comment: Optasports seem to be more of a paid service, but squakwa is a very useful resource albeit with limited years.